# how to set the visibility of menu item while respective fragment is open?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

Actually I m using navigation drawer but on back button menu item is not visible while the respective fragment is opened.How to set the visibility of menu item?Can anyone help me?

```
    @Override    
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        Fragment fragment = null;
        int id = item.getItemId();


        navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setActionView(R.layout.menu_home);
        navigationView.getMenu().getItem(1).setActionView(R.layout.menu_profile);
        navigationView.getMenu().getItem(2).setActionView(R.layout.menu_history);
        navigationView.getMenu().getItem(3).setActionView(R.layout.menu_contact_igrab);
        navigationView.getMenu().getItem(4).setActionView(R.layout.menu_help);
        navigationView.getMenu().getItem(5).setActionView(R.layout.menu_logout);



        if (id == R.id.home) {
            item.setActionView(R.layout.menu_home_blue);

            changeFragments(new CustomerHomeFragment());


        } else if (id == R.id.my_profile) {
            item.setActionView(R.layout.menu_my_profile_blue);
            changeFragments(new CustomerProfileFragment()); } DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Can you share any snap which can describe your issue in more details?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `setUserVisibleHint` method. Override the method and check if `isVisibleToUser` parameter is `true` and `getActivity()` is not `null`.

Comment: Post your code how you are implementing this to make the menu item visible.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setChecked()` method for set selection navigation item.
make method in your activity:

```
public void setNavigation(int id) {
        navigationView.getMenu().getItem(id).setChecked(true);
    }
```

now call this method in your fragment for navigation item selection :

```
((YourActivity)mContext).setNavigation(int position);
```

Hope it will help you!!

Comment: I want to select the particular menu item while respective fragment is opened.But it takes previous selected value.

Comment: you calling all fragments from navigationItemSelected method? right ?

Comment: yes.. but when I return from profile fragment to home fragment then profile menu item is selected rather than home menu item.

Comment: yes that's i told you in your profile fragment call `((YourActivity)mContext).setNavigation(int position);` method. now remember position will be your home fragment. i did same in my project. its working fine.

Comment: can u told me how i implement this method?

Comment: i already done in ans. you just create first method in your container activity and second method you have to call on fragment where you replacing.

Answer (score 0):

First set `visiblity` **false** of all the `item` like :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_dashboard"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard"
        android:title="@string/nav_dashboard"
        android:visible="false" />
</group>
</menu>
```

Now in `Activity` you can show and hide `item` like this.

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
Menu menu =navigationView.getMenu();
MenuItem nav_dashboard = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_dashboard);
nav_dashboard.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: but due to this initially visibility of all menu item is gone then how i select the items..sorry for my English  i hope u will understand what i m trying to say...

Comment: Item which you want to show you can set there visiblity true according to any condition